# Syntax error: Unexpected token when implementing reducer in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, babeljs

When I build my application using gulp, gulp keeps giving me a syntax error:

```
SyntaxError: /Users/USER/Documents/portfolio_projects/USER_PROJECT/PROJECT/src/main/webapp/src/reducers/AuthorizationReducer.js: 
Unexpected token (12:4) while parsing file: /Users/USER/Documents/portfolio_projects/USER_PROJECT/PROJECT/src/main/webapp/src/reducers/AuthorizationReducer.js]
pos: 261,
loc: { line: 12, column: 4 }
```

AuthorizationReducer.js:

```
import ActionType from '../actions/ActionType';

const defaultState = {
    signedIn: false,
    isAuthorizing: false
}

const AuthorizationReducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ActionType.Authorization.REQUEST:
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthorizing: true
            };
        case ActionType.Authorization.SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                signedIn: true,
                isAuthorizing: false
            };
        case ActionType.Authorization.FAILURE:
            return {
                ...state,
                signedIn: false,
                isAuthorizing: false
            };
    }
    return state;
}

export default AuthorizationReducer;
```

ActionType.js

```
const ActionType = {

Authorization: {
    REQUEST: '',
    SUCCESS: '',
    FAILURE: ''
  }
}

const ActionTypeHax: any = ActionType;
Object.keys(ActionTypeHax).forEach(category => {
    Object.keys(ActionTypeHax[category]).forEach(actionType => {
        ActionTypeHax[category][actionType] = category + '.' + actionType;
    });
});

module.export = ActionType;
```

I just don't see what's wrong here. As far as I can tell the syntax here is correct for implementing a reducer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eyeballing the line numbers, it looks like it's complaining about the use of the object spread operator.  That's an in-progress Javascript syntax proposal, and only works if you have your transpiler (such as Babel) properly configured to handle it.

Comment: This helped although I didn't configure my transpiler, instead I used the `Object.assign()` method.

Comment: Yeah, Babel just transpiles `...someObject` down to `Object.assign({}, someObject)`, so that's fine.  If you do get tired of using object spreads, especially for nested data, I have a list of many immutable update utility libs over at https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/immutable-data.md.  The dot-prop-immutable lib seems nice, but there's plenty of options to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

- check if exists `"babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1"` in package.json
- check if exists presets: `['react', 'es2015', 'stage-3']` in the webpack.config.js module:

  ```
  {
      rules: [{
          exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, //Check for all js files
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          query: {
              presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-3']
          }
      }]
  }
  ```